# Can someone tell me how to fix this error , here I'm working with tensorflow fashion_mnish dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Here is the code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_image[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_label[i]])
plt.show()
```

Here is an error that occur when I run the above code

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 7     plt.grid(False)
  8     plt.imshow(train_image[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
  9     plt.xlabel(class_names[train_label[i]])
 10 plt.show()

  TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: What's `class_names`?  A list?  If so you can only index it with a number.  What is `train_label[i]`?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell, as I don't know which form your variables have. My guess would be that:

plt.xlabel(class_names[train_label[i]])

train_label[i] is not returning an integer. Can you check if train_label is an int and not float?

My other guess would be that the resulting shape of train_label[i] is not correct.

Comment: train_label is an ndarray         and      class_names  is an list

Comment: It depends on which data type is inside the ndarray. You can check with  train_label.dtype. if this returns int32 or int64, it's not the problem.

Comment: dtype('uint8')    this data type is inside the ndarray